# Prob. 18, Chap. 5, in Baby Rudin: Another Form of Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Here is Prob. 18, Chap. 5, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $[a, b]$, $n$ is a positive integer, and $f^{(n-1)}$ exists for every $t \in [a, b]$. Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $P$ be as in Taylor's theorem (5.15). Define $$ Q(t) = \frac{ f(t) - f(\beta) }{ t- \beta} $$ for $t \in [a, b]$, $t \neq \beta$, differentiate $$ f(t) - f(\beta) = (t-\beta) Q(t) $$ $n-1$ times at $t = \alpha$, and derive the following version of Taylor's theorem: $$ f(\beta) = P(\beta) + \frac{Q^{(n-1)}(\alpha)}{(n-1)!} (\beta - \alpha)^n. $$

And, here is Theorem 5.15 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $[a, b]$, $n$ is a positive integer, $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $f^{(n)}(t)$ exists for every $t \in (a, b)$. Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be distinct points of $[a, b]$, and define $$ P(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k!} \left( t-\alpha \right)^k.$$
> Then there exists a point $x$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
> $$ f(\beta) = P(\beta) + \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} (\beta - \alpha )^n.$$

An Attempt:

> For all $t \in [a, b]$, we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> f(t) - f(\beta) &= ( t-\beta) Q(t),  \tag{1} \\
> f^\prime(t) &= Q(t) + (t-\beta) Q^\prime(t), \tag{2} \\
> f^{\prime\prime}(t) &= 2Q^\prime(t) + (t-\beta) Q^{\prime\prime}(t),  \tag{3} \\
> f^{(3)}(t) &= 3 Q^{\prime\prime}(t) + (t-\beta)Q^{(3)}(t), \tag{4} \\
> f^{(4)}(t) &= 4 Q^{(3)}(t) + (t-\beta) Q^{(4)}(t), \tag{5} \\ 
> \cdots &= \cdots \\
> f^{(n-1)}(t) &= (n-1) Q^{(n-2)}(t) + (t-\beta) Q^{(n-1)}(t). \tag{*} 
> \end{align}
> $$
> So, for $t = \alpha$, the above chain of equations yields
> $$ 
> \begin{align}
> & \qquad f(\beta) \\
> &= f(\alpha) + Q(\alpha)  (\beta - \alpha )  \qquad \mbox{ [ using (1) ] } \\
> &= f(\alpha) +  \left[ f^\prime(\alpha) + (\beta - \alpha) Q^\prime(\alpha) \right] (\beta - \alpha ) \\ 
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (2) ] } \\
> &= f(\alpha) + f^\prime(\alpha) (\beta - \alpha) +  Q^\prime(\alpha) (\beta - \alpha)^2  \\
> &= f(\alpha) +  f^\prime(\alpha) (\beta - \alpha) \\ 
> & \qquad +  \left[  \frac{1}{2} \left( f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha) + (\beta - \alpha) Q^{\prime\prime}(\alpha) \right) \right] (\beta - \alpha)^2 \\ 
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (3) ] } \\
> &= f(\alpha) +  \frac{f^\prime(\alpha)}{1!} (\beta - \alpha) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2!} (\beta - \alpha)^2 + \frac{Q^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2!} (\beta - \alpha)^3 \\ 
> &=  f(\alpha) +  f^\prime(\alpha) (\beta - \alpha) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2} (\beta - \alpha)^2 + \frac{\frac{1}{3} \left( f^{(3)}(\alpha) + (\beta - \alpha) Q^{(3)}(\alpha) \right) }{2} (\beta - \alpha)^3 \qquad \mbox{ [ using (4) ] } \\ 
> &=  f(\alpha) +  \frac{f^\prime(\alpha)}{1!} (\beta - \alpha) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2!} (\beta - \alpha)^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(\alpha)}{3!}(\beta-\alpha)^3 + \frac{Q^{(3)}(\alpha)}{3!} (\beta-\alpha)^4 \\ 
> &=  f(\alpha) +  \frac{f^\prime(\alpha)}{1!} (\beta - \alpha) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2!} (\beta - \alpha)^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(\alpha)}{3!}(\beta-\alpha)^3 + \frac{ \frac{1}{4} \left( f^{(4)}(\alpha) + (\beta - \alpha) Q^{(4)}(\alpha) \right)  }{3!}  (\beta-\alpha)^4 \\ 
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (5) ] } \\
> &= f(\alpha) +  \frac{f^\prime(\alpha)}{1!} (\beta - \alpha) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2!} (\beta - \alpha)^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(\alpha)}{3!}(\beta-\alpha)^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(\alpha)}{4!} (\beta - \alpha)^4 + \frac{Q^{(4)}(\alpha)}{4!} (\beta-\alpha)^5 \\
> &= \cdots \\
> &= f(\alpha) +  \frac{f^\prime(\alpha)}{1!} (\beta - \alpha) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\alpha)}{2!} (\beta - \alpha)^2 \\ 
> & \qquad + \frac{f^{(3)}(\alpha)}{3!}(\beta-\alpha)^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(\alpha)}{4!} (\beta - \alpha)^4 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(n-1)}(\alpha)}{(n-1)!} (\beta-\alpha)^{n-1} + \frac{Q^{(n-1)}(\alpha)}{(n-1)!} (\beta - \alpha)^n \\
> &= P(\beta) +  \frac{Q^{(n-1)}(\alpha)}{(n-1)!} (\beta - \alpha)^n, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> as required.

Is this proof correct? If so, then is it rigorous enough for Rudin as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with this proof, I think it's valid. If you want to make it more rigorous, you can prove by induction that
$$Q^{(k)}(t) = \frac{f^{(k)}(t) + (\beta - t)Q^{(k+1)}(t)}{k+1},$$
for integer $k$, where $0\leq k \leq n-2$.

And then also prove the desired goal by induction.